# when I use the DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged to be the trigger of UpDatePanel，it dosn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, updatepanel

And the tip is the “DropDownList1” didn't find “DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged”

```
</asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

   <ContentTemplate>

    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 

        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">

        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>

    </asp:DropDownList>

   </ContentTemplate>

        <Triggers>

            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" EventName="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" /> 

        </Triggers>
```

Please tell me How to make it work!

Comment: Not sure about the Asp world but in other frameworks you specify the events name, not the event handlers name, Try `EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"` and see if it works

Comment: Because your update panel mode is not conditional you just need to add AutoPostBack=True like what @Scott Selby said

Answer (score 2):

you need `AutoPostBack=True`

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True"   
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
```